# How do I make a custom tab bar which pops up when a button is pressed?

Tags: ios

How can I create a custom popup tab bar. that has a small button and once pressed it appears from the bottm and it goes back when the small button get pressed again?

Comment: Please stop prefixing all of your question titles with the version of Xcode you are using. It should only be in a tag, and only then if your question is actually about Xcode (the IDE), not anything you happen to be writing using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate the position of a view by changing its `center` or `frame` property within an animation block. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) for documentation.

You essentially create your view off the screen, then animate it onto the screen:

```
// View is off the bottom of the screen
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,480,320,44)];

// Animate it onto the screen
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{myView.frame = CGRectMake(0,436,320,44);}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could drag a TabBar in your interface from IB and set yourself as its delegate to respond to the selection of bar items. Since a TabBar is a view you should be able to animate it on/off the screen at the touch of a button.